# Is creating a professional Facebook account considered suspicious?

Tags: professionalism, networking, clients

I would like to create a professional Facebook account to interact with the people I work with and with potential clients.

What I fear is that potential future employers or clients find a professional account suspicious while having a personal account.

Is it badly seen to have a professional Facebook account? If not, is it considered rude to tell a professional that sends an invitation to your personal account "please add me on my professional account"?

**EDIT :** I need to create a professional Facebook account because I'm creating a company and meeting potential future clients to whom I give my name. Most of them add me on LinkedIn but some just add me on Facebook (I really don't see why either).

And as I don't want them to see my personal life and telling them "I won't accept your invite add me on LinkedIn" can be considered rude I want to create a professional Facebook account to fix that.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want a "professional facebook" instead of using a dedicated professional social media service like LinkedIn?

Comment: It's called LinkedIn ;) [Edit: @Erik you beat me to it...]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60423/discussion-on-question-by-sh5164-is-creating-a-professional-facebook-account-con).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'd say it's unlikely to be suspicious. Even assuming you have both of them publicly visible (the people I know who have two accounts, will hide their private one to force business contacts to the other one) it seems pretty common for people to have two separate networks.

If anyone asks why you have two, just saying "I don't want to bother professional contacts with status updates about my cat" will almost certainly settle it for them.

Everyone has different expectations from a social media service, and especially if you use it for two purposes it really helps to have two accounts. In the end, Facebook decides what you see, not you, so having two accounts will ensure you have both fun-social content *and* professional content, rather than one drowning out the other due to what you interact with. Not mixing the two for your contacts is an added bonus for everyone; just as your colleagues don't care about your cat, it's likely your brothers don't care about your job details.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice. Now they are suspicious since they know I don't have a cat :(

Comment: @DVK Sounds like it's time to get out there and get some cat

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Just get a load of boxes. There's half a chance that a cat is in each box. (Source: [physics.se])

Comment: I have a cat, this plan is flawless.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, Followed your advice. I made a Cat box openning video, got a few dead cat, and now Peta is at my door.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You got half a chance for a **living** cat. But what are you gonna do with all that dead cats?

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e9/b9/d4/e9b9d4f1fb0192ae28a2bd6514d784a0.jpg

Comment: If you lack a cat, you can also use baby pictures, BDSM-related content, dog pictures, or furry erotica. Or all of them at once.

Comment: @TSar I'll go for the cat

Comment: If you're a celebrity, you can grab a cat, and they'll just let you do that.

Comment: @draganddrop You don't *open the box*.  That never ends well, sometimes.

Comment: @DragandDrop [this person was a bit more lucky](http://imgur.com/a/fWrqS).

Answer (score 16):

Have you considered getting a facebook Page instead? They are pretty much made for this purpose, and gives a much more professional impression than a personal account.

Having two "personal" accounts is not suspicious, but it is a bit annoying. I have a couple of contacts that does this - on one of them I am friend with both accounts, meaning for example I get two birthday notifications for her etc. Which account would you hide from search results? Regardless you will have to explain to a lot of people to use a different account. Denying someone access to one of the accounts can be seen as kind of rude.

Comment: This is what friends with small businesses use, or self-employed people.  It's quite nice because you can control the link between business and pleasure, (a complete firewall may be appropriate in some fields, in others some cautious sharing is normal). It also saves messing around with different logins and the consequent chances of accidentally posting to the wrong account.

Comment: @JanErikGunnar I don't know where you're from but in France I think it's kind of considered "cocky" since Facebook Pages are more related to celebrities than professionals

Comment: The "page" would be the way to go - you create it for your business. You can even invite your friends to "like" it to generate some buzz (if that's appropriate at this stage), _and_ put the link to it on your business cards that you're handing out. (Throw the QR code to the "page" on there to make it easy for your new business contacts to find the correct version of "you" on FB.)

Comment: I am in Sweden. I don't think it's considered "cocky" here if you have at least some kind of legitimate business, and I doubt regardless of location, it would ever be considered any more cocky than referring your friends/connections to different accounts depending on how they know you

Answer (score 16):

In addition to other answers considering the professional impact, note that creating two Facebook accounts goes against [Facebook Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/terms), and also what you want to do is explicitly forbidden :

> 4. Registration and Account Security
>
>    - You will not provide any false personal information on
>        Facebook, or create an account for anyone other than yourself without
>        permission.
>    - You will not create more than one personal account.
>    - You will not use your personal timeline primarily for your
>        own commercial gain, and will use a Facebook Page for such purposes.

Comment: Exactly what I've written, it's highly unprofessional to create account that break terms of use.

Comment: I knew very few people who only have one Facebook account

Comment: Still good to know it goes against the rules, then again no one is going to check (I'm naughty I know)

Comment: @sh5164 I would hardly say "no one is going to check".   What actually happens is an evildoer attacks the system.  As they react, it dawns on the abuse team that *they an algorithmically detect that MO*.  Out pops a list of 150K candidates, they flog out some obvious false positives, then drop the whole 147K in the grinder.  Fragging you isn't a failure because you *were* violating.

Answer (score 14):

There is a partial alternative solution provided by Facebook. You can add Facebook Friends to different lists, examples from my account:

- Good Friends
- Family
- Restricted
- [Area where I live]

The "Restricted" lists seems like a good fit for colleagues or bosses. It prevents them from seeing all activity except:

- Posts you tag them in
- Activity you change to Public
- Posts you make as

You can still message Restricted Friends.

https://www.facebook.com/help/206571136073851#What-happens-when-I-add-someone-to-the-Restricted-list

Comment: Seems like a good solution, are people aware when you put them on "restricted" ?

Comment: @sh5164 I know at one time when I messed with groups the folks were notified.  Not sure if that is true or not *now*.  Test it out with a good buddy to be sure.

Comment: @MisterPositive Ok I'll do, I'll edit my question with the result

Comment: It oughtn't notify friends. They might notice that you have no photos or posts if everything you've posted has been Friends Only.

Comment: This is a good approach to take when you're in a company where it's considered normal for all employees and managers to be "Facebook friends", but it's probably overly complicated and prone to going wrong if you actually want to interact with both groups.

Comment: I would absolutely not trust Facebook to keep information away from the restricted group.

Comment: @sh5164: +1 to what Kat said. I would *not* rely on this feature. Any interactions you have with content that might be public is still far more visible than it would be with a separate account.

Comment: @Kat +1 Their motto is "move fast and break things", and as an advertiser, I can attest.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a 100% reliable system? There will always be loopholes, screenshots etc. This is the Internet, and people are persistent.

Answer (score 8):

It depends what kind of work you do.

I am an **engineer**, so my "Professional Facebook" is my **Linkedin**, and this is the most appropriate social network for a more **"strait-laced"** job.

For other types of work a Facebook **page** is entirely appropriate. These tend to be work that is **creative** and/or **dealing with the public**. It is a good idea to use some kind of professional name, distinct from your personal account to avoid confusion. This is why Facebook has pages for "business" and "musician band." (and for "artist" too, I believe.)

Besides being an engineer, I am also a musician. **My band has its own Facebook page and Youtube account.** I don't have my own facebook Musician page, but if I was serious about being a solo artist, I would.

My sister is a freelance **music teacher** and **craft fair organiser** and has two separate professional facebook pages beside her personal one - one for each of her two businesses.

**Bars** have Facebook pages. **Photographers** have Facebook and Instagram pages. Even **builders** have facebook pages, in additional to their professional website (if any.) Even suppliers of engineering software have facebook pages, as an informal user community.

In summary, yes it is a good idea to have a facebook page IF it is appropriate to your line of work, but you should give it a name related to your work to avoid confusion with your personal page.

Answer (score 3):

"Professional" Facebook account?  I wouldn't necessarily deem it as suspicious, but as the others have mentioned, it's rather superfluous in light of the fact that LinkedIn is the de facto site for professional social media.

To add to that, Facebook frowns on multiple accounts.  You may invest lots of time on said "professional" account, to end up having it get [closed by the powers-that-be](https://www.facebook.com/help/975828035803295?helpref=uf_permalink).

Lastly, I subscribe to the old adage of not mixing business with pleasure.  If strictly-professional contacts are sending friend requests to your personal Facebook account, *decline* them.  I'd bypass this idea of multiple accounts entirely, for the simple fact that there are things in my personal life that my professional contacts just ***never*** need to have access to.  I'd hate to toy with the very high risk that with multiple Facebook accounts, I'd eventually mix them up and post the wrong content to the wrong account; even though it can be deleted later, the *exposure* cannot be, and as we see in the news each day, the consequences can be severe.

Comment: At least in the UK, it depends greatly on the business which site is defacto. I have engineer friends on LinkedIn. I also have friends who are artists, fencing instructors, have businesses making clothing or are magicians or musicians and they all have business facebook pages in addition to their personal facebook pages. I would never look for any of those businesses on LinkedIn.

Comment: It's also nice for "artists with day jobs" so they can be a musician on Facebook and an ad-agency manager on Linkedin.

Answer (score 3):

### I think employers will find it concerning

Employers and recruiters are screening you for [scary stuff](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-potential-employers-check-your-facebook-page.html) on your social media -- and *they know **you know** they're looking*.  Their minds are not on innocent reasons you might do this.  When they see two accounts, *it looks like concealment*: it looks like gaming their screening process.  Which they see all the time.

*In their world*, the simplest explanation is the most likely.  Occam's Razor: you're a baddie.

You will need to overcome that bias, and that will depend on their willingness to spend extra time to let you.

The nagging question in their minds will be "why did you do that", when you could've just had accounts on two different social media platforms *like everyone else*... i.e. a Facebook account for personal and a Linkedin account for professional.

### Facebook will be actively hunting you

It's a violation of Facebook TOS to create two accounts.  Most of the time these accounts are for sockpuppeting or other system abuses, and Facebook is on the hunt for them.  If both of them have your correct identity, that makes you stupid-easy to catch.

Do you really know how to do a browser cookie reset? Clear local storage?  Flash storage?  It's a constant arms race, as developers try to come up with "supercookies" you can't easily clear. How about IPv6?  I'm good at this stuff and I continue to be astounded when I see a highly targeted ad after I was sure I reset everything.   Forget about apps - on most phones, Facebook app functionality is too deeply woven into the phone's OS to be able to reset.

Most of the time, account bans are highly arbitrary, because the abuse team is regularly deploying various detection methods, and they just happen to catch you.  The account will suddenly just be gone, with no advance notice and no reason why.  This can be devastating if you lose a Page or other feature because you are the only admin.

Macs support multiple users (PCs too I hear) and thats probably as good as you'll get for defeating cookies, supercookies etc. But still, same IP address, same first and last name, same birthday, etc...

### It confuses your friends

They will search for you and get two hits.  With luck, they'll try to befriend *both of you*.  This will be even worse if you falsify some info on one account.  They will be confused when you ask them to "please friend my personal|professional account instead" (you're doing the weird thing so you need to do the legwork). Keep in mind, most people let Facebook scrape/surveil their email and contacts, so they'll connect to you via the email they have.

You are probably better off being outbound and friending *them first*, or answering their friend request with your own friend request from the correct account.

### It will confuse *you*

And you will get confused yourself.  You will find yourself on the wrong account all the time.   Like I say, switching without being detected is super tricky.  You may be better off using one Facebook account always on one device, and another always on another device.  Or a different user login on your PC.

### Officially Not On Facebook

I've seen it work when the person is *Officially Not On Facebook*, but has a secret account for utility reasons (e.g. perhaps he runs Facebook ads).  He uses a sensible pseudonym and he only tells people who need to know. They understand that his presence is only for utility, not for being social - so they don't engage him socially.  It's still a TOS violation, but given their low usage they are unlikely to be caught.